# Keras - How should I specify the input_shape of my training data? (The data are gray-scale images)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm using `Conv2d` in Keras to do some classification for gray-scale images. Each image is stored as a 240*300 matrix, (namely a list `[ A_1, A_2,..., A_240 ]` and each `A_k` is a list of length 300

How should I specify the `input_shape` of the first layer of my ConvNet?

Thanks

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer:
>   expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received
>       : [None, 240, 300]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to reshape your data, adding a dimension at the end with size of one, which represents one channel (a grayscale image). Assuming `data` has shape `(samples, 240, 300)`:

```
data = data.reshape((-1, 240, 300, 1))
```

This will make `data` have shape `(samples, 240, 300, 1)`. Then to your first layer you should give `input_shape=(240, 300, 1)`